# Search on username

Tags: discussion, search

Why do I have to go to SO/users to search on username.

Why can't I just use the 'normal' searchbox with for example my username.

`user:peehaa` but I have to use my id `user:508666`.

Is this by design? And if so: Why?

Comment: @Wether: They aren't??? Ok that's new for me. Why aren't they?

Comment: Why should they be? It's a lot easier when people can just use whatever they want instead of trying to find a unique string of characters on a site with hundreds of thousands of users.

Comment: @AdamLear Because a user with an unregistered account will have multiple accounts, and it's impossible to find them all. There's an open feature request, [Let diamond moderators (or even regular users) search for unregistered users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314953/139866). Of course it's normally more useful to search by ID, but not being able to search by name is a bug IMO. Even searching (filtering) by name of the Users page doesn't show unregistered accounts. >:-(

Comment: @ChrisW This discussion isn't about searching for users. It's about searching within posts made by a user. I don't have an opinion off the top of my head about adding unregistered users to the /users filter... but it looks like the other post picked up the [status-review] tag a bit ago, so it'll get on our radar.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Usernames are not unique. That allows people who want to use their real names as username to do so without going through the cumbersome real-name-changing process.

Or, for that matter, allows users to chose whatever stupid nickname they want, like `Wether`.

Comment: This does not answer the question of why we can't search for posts by username. The text in questions isn't unique either but we can use those as keywords.