# Let diamond moderators (or even regular users) search for unregistered users

Tags: feature-request, status-review, unregistered-users, users-page, user-search

Unregistered users don't show up as searchable in a site's [user list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users), but diamond moderators may need to look them up from time to time on account of their interactions with the site. Regular users may also want to be able to do that in their capacity as community moderators.

Could diamond moderators and/or regular users please be given the option to include unregistered users in a user list search?

Comment: I would really love this feature and the userscripts I could build on top of this

Comment: Moderators can already search for unregistered users. They just don't have a page listing all the unregistered users.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I posted this back when I was a diamond moderator, and I couldn't run searches for unregistered users at the time. As in, [on the users page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users), if I typed in a known unregistered user's name, I'd get no results at all. Has that changed?

Comment: It's on the _Admin Tools_ page ( /admin/links), _Find Users by Credential, Email, Website, or DisplayName_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Smort. Thanks!